# Combine two arrays with different format in JavaScript / ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays. How can I combine them?

```js
const array1 = [
    "value one",
    "value two"
]

const array2 = [
    {
        "title": "title one",
    },
    {
        "title": "title two",
    }
]

const finalArray =[...array1, ...array2.title]

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the map

```js
const array1 = [
    "value one",
    "value two"
]

const array2 = [
    {
        "title": "title one",
    },
    {
        "title": "title two",
    }
]

const finalArray =[...array1, ...array2.map(i => i.title)]

console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: thanks @Sachila Ranawaka this is working fine.